# How can I use fields in inherited model in odoo 10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I inherited model stock.picking. And i want to create Validation on adding value to quantity receive(qty_done fields) and compare it to quantity order(product_qty fields) and both fields are from stock.picking model. Any help? thanks

```
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class StockPickingInherited(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    @api.constrains('product_qty', 'qty_done')
    def _check_qty(self):

    if self.product_qty < self.qty_done:
        raise ValidationError ('Error')
```

is this correct? but nothing happens. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried same class name which is given in the `stock.picking model` class?

```
class StockPicking(models.Model):
```

Comment: If I couldn't find the way you are thinking, feel free to fix the reformatting.

Comment: check if you import your file in `__init__.py`

Comment: did you print something while constrains?

Comment: yes but printing self.product_qty and self.qty_done didn't work

Comment: i also tried same name like stock.picking but it doesn't work also. please help

Comment: @api.one above @api.constrains('product_qty', 'qty_done')